# How to bundle custom JRE with jar file for running on Linux?

Tags: java, jar, bundle

I am on my way to making my java app run on all platforms(Windows, Linux, and Mac). I know that jar files already run on all platforms, but I need to bundle it with my custom JRE(created with jlink).

For windows, I have already bundled my custom JRE with Launch4j. Now remains Mac, and Linux.

Since exe won't run on them, I need to get my custom JRE bundled with the jar file. How do I do it?

Also, is the custom jre I created on windows going to work on Mac an linux?

Comment: Are you looking for jpackage?

Comment: Can jpackage bundle JRE with the generated output file? Or is it just about converting jar to supported types by other platforms? I never heard it.

Comment: jpackage can create a platform-specific installer (deb, dmg, exe, ...) using a JRE created by jlink (or by creating one in the same process). Jpackage is also part of the jdk.

Comment: Would you explain "or by creating one in the same process?"  Did you mean that packaging your jar with jpackage, including what jlink does with the same jpackage command?

Comment: jpackage can either use the JRE created by jlink or create the JRE just like jlink does.

Comment: By using the `--module-path` and the `--add-modules` attributes, aren' I right?

Comment: You can take a look at [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html)